# What is the React official position for throwing promises inside render functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, react-suspense

There is a new cool feature in React — Suspense component. Currently it only officially supports components created using React.lazy function. But unofficially it well known that internally Suspense component is triggered by throwing a promise deeper in the render tree and there are some libraries that have already adopted this technique to bring a new cool developer experience, for example:

- [react-i18next](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next)
- [react-relay](https://github.com/facebook/relay/tree/master/packages/react-relay)
- [react-query](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query)

Also there is a core react package [react-cache](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/packages/react-cache) which uses it (unofficially of course).

Having all this in mind I'm kinda confused because there is no any mention in React Docs about throwing promises (in other words what triggers Suspense component) but at the same time there are lots of talks and libraries that use it. In twitter discussion [dan abramov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/458193/dan-abramov) replied that [the API will likely change](https://twitter.com/orimarron/status/1192819299368521731). But still the situation is confusing.

So the question is: Is it safe to start using this technique in the production? If not, then how can I use libraries (even facebook based) that have already adopted it? Finally, if the API (throwing promises) is the subject to be changed in future, can I be assured that it's just a tiny change that I need to adopt in my own implementation?

Thanks folks!

**Update**

According to these issues ([one](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17621), [two](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17526)) it seems like they still not sure about the future API. Most likely they will offer a public API (probably they mean [react-cache](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/packages/react-cache) or something more general) which is essentially just a wrapper around throwing Promise mechanism.

Answer (score 11):

### Short answer

No, it's not safe.
Even if other libraries uses it you should not write code on the basis of React internals (and certainly not in production!)

### Long answer

Those libraries that uses React internals will probably bump a new version compatible with every new version of React - it's kind of the maintainers job.

The problem that you could run into is that the maintainers won't update their libraries to support the latest version of React, and that would hold you down to an old version of React.

Anyhow, in cases like relay, you can use the library without worry too much about the maintenance. Libraries like relay are heavily used from Facebook (at least from what I know), so the maintenance won't be a problem.

### Using React internals in your application

That's a very bad idea (in my opinion).
If you want to do that it means that you'll need to keep up with the React internals.
If the API of suspense changes (and they will) you'll need to rewrite all the components that uses that API in order to upgrade React, which is not funny.

If you want my advice: stick with the official versions of React.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I agree with you. The situation is becoming more and more dangerous since lots of popular libraries are already using it. I do hope that eventually the low level API will remain the same and they'll just offer a stable public API.

Answer (score 2):

React discourages throwing promises inside funtions to suspend components. This is due to the fact that it is subject to change in future. It is **December 2023** and the current version in town is ***react 18***.

It is explicitly mentioned that ability to suspend components will be moved to react hooks in future. This means that components that `throw` a promise with intention to suspend, will be stripped off this ability in future versions of react. And react weighs towards `use` hook as a way to trigger a component to suspend.
Here is an excerpt from the [rfcs specs](https://github.com/acdlite/rfcs/blob/first-class-promises/text/0000-first-class-support-for-promises.md#enable-compiler-driven-optimizations):

> For example, in the current version of React, an unstable mechanism allows arbitrary functions to suspend during render by throwing a promise. We will be removing this in future releases in favor of `use`. This means only Hooks will be allowed to suspend

It can be hard to keep up with react internals as it is subject to unpredictable change in future. So a betterway to suspend a component would be through use of the [`use`](https://react.dev/reference/react/use) hook as it is guaranteed to work in future versions of react despite internals that may change.

Answer (score 0):

in 2022 year you can throw promise to trigger Suspense

```js
const Component = () => {

  // this trigger ErrorBoundary
  throw new Error()

  // this trigger Suspense
  throw new Promise()

}
```

if tou throuthted object has `.then` method, React will think that is Promise

Comment: Is it officially supported and documented now?

Comment: it's official and it came with react 18. i documentation it's called `resource`

Comment: @Bergi i think this not be changed https://17.reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hey Ivan, I'm not sure if it's official as it's still marked as an experimental feature in React Docs. The only mention I could find is https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html#suspense-in-data-frameworks where they stated that it's still not recommended.

Comment: There are some 3rd-party libraries that officially support Suspense now (e.g. Next.js) but I still haven't found any official documentation on how to use it for arbitrary data fetching (i.e. how the API actually works).

Comment: React’s [aynsc/await proposal](https://github.com/acdlite/rfcs/blob/first-class-promises/text/0000-first-class-support-for-promises.md#usepromise:~:text=For%20example%2C%20in%20the%20current%20version%20of%20React%2C%20an%20unstable%20mechanism%20allows%20arbitrary%20functions%20to%20suspend%20during%20render%20by%20throwing%20a%20promise.%20We%20will%20be%20removing%20this%20in%20future%20releases%20in%20favor%20of%20use.) explicitly calls this out, and intends to remove the ability to suspend by throwing promises, in favour of a new solution